# ORACLE SQL: Hourly Date to be group by day time and sum of the amount

Tags: sql, oracle, date

I have the following situation:

```
ID                DATE_TIME             AMOUNT
23     14-MAY-2021 10:47:01               5
23     14-MAY-2021 11:49:52               3
23     14-MAY-2021 12:03:18               4
```

How can get the sum of the amount and take the DATE by day not hourly?

Example:

```
ID                DATE_TIME           TOTAL
23                20210514             12
```

I tried this way but i got error:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ID, TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD'), SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ID ='23' AND DATE_TIME > SYSDATE-1
GROUP BY TOTAL, DATE_TIME
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need DISTINCT if you use GROUP BY - anything that is grouped must be distinct unless it joined to something else later on that caused it to repeat again

You were almost there too

```
SELECT ID, TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD') AS DATE_TIME, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ID ='23' AND DATE_TIME > SYSDATE-1
GROUP BY ID, TO_CHAR(DATE_TIME, 'YYYYMMDD')
```

You need to group by the output of the function, not the input. Not every database can GROUP BY aliases used in the select (technically the SELECT hasn't been done by the time the GROUP is done so the aliases don't exist yet, and you wouldnt group by the *total* because that's an aggregate (the result of summing up every various value in the group)

---

If you need to do further work with that date, don't convert it to a string.. Cut the time off using TRUNC:

```
SELECT ID, TRUNC(DATE_TIME) as DATE_TIME, SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL 
FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE ID ='23' AND DATE_TIME > SYSDATE-1
GROUP BY ID, TRUNC(DATE_TIME)
```

TRUNC can cut a date down to other parts, for example TRUNC(DATE_TIME, 'HH24') will remove the minutes and seconds but leave the hours

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `DATE` column to a string with the required accuracy and then group on that:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       TO_CHAR("DATE", 'YYYY-MM-DD'),
       SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE  ID ='23'
AND    "DATE" > SYSDATE-1
GROUP BY ID, TO_CHAR("DATE", 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

or truncate the value so that the time component is set to midnight for each date:

```sql
SELECT ID,
       TRUNC("DATE"),
       SUM(AMOUNT) AS TOTAL FROM MY_TABLE
WHERE  ID ='23'
AND    "DATE" > SYSDATE-1
GROUP BY ID, TRUNC("DATE")
```

*(Note: `DATE` is a keyword and cannot be used as an identifier unless you use a quoted-identifier; and you would need to use the quotes, and the exact case, everytime you refer to the column. You would be better to rename the column to something else that is not a keyword.)*

Comment: I experimented with this a bit a couple of years ago, I posted the findings on OTN (I can probably dig it up if interested). For whatever reason - we can speculate on that - using `trunc(dt)` in `group by` is nontrivially faster than using `to_char(dt)`, even if in the `select` clause we must use `to_char` on the result of `trunc(dt)`. A bit counter-intuitive perhaps; whenever I post tests, I post all the code and details, so the test can be replicated.